# Get Header from Request in SoapUI groovy script

Tags: groovy, http-headers, soapui

I want to get the value of the "Accept" Header from a SoapUI request. Then I want to store it in a TestCase property.

That is what I'm trying to do from a Groovy script TestStep:

```
//Get Accept Header from request (if Accept Header does not exist default to empty string)
def acceptHeader = context.testCase.getTestStepAt(0).testRequest.requestHeaders.get("Accept", "")

//Set Accept Header Value to current TestCase properties
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("acceptHeaderSet", acceptHeader)
```

The first TestStep of the TestCase is a REST Request and the second TestStep is the mentioned script.

Each time that I run the TestCase the default value is set (it seems that it does not find any header)

Any idea about what is happening? Is this a bug in the SoapUI tool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:
    testRunner.getResults()[0].getRequestHeaders()["Accept"]

This will only work if you run the entire testcase, otherwise there are no results to get. Maybe your method ran into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to settle such situation using properties. Just define property (e.g. on project level) and then change its value. Like described here [Script access to properties](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this is not a suitable solution for me because of that:

- I use a dynamic property that auto-generates randomly a value for the Header.

- In a next step I need to know which value was setted for the header to make another request with the same value.

Comment: Probably I didn't understand complexity of the problem but you can set value of property before request, transfer it into the next step, change (or read value). Anyway, it is a pretty interesting question.

Comment: Really smart response. I changed my tests to follow your suggested approach. Thanks!